# Can someone please point out error for the code "Number of Subsequences That Satisfy the Given Sum Condition" which is giving stack overflow error

Tags: java, algorithm, stack-overflow

This is leetCode problem. I solved it using the following method but its giving stack overflow error.

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target.
Return the number of non-empty subsequences of nums such that the sum of the minimum and maximum element on it is less or equal than the target.
Since the answer may be too large, return it modulo 10^9 + 7.
Input: nums = [3,5,6,7], target = 9
Output: 4
Explanation: There are 4 subsequences that satisfy the condition.
[3] : Min value + max value <= target (3 + 3 <= 9)
[3,5] : (3 + 5 <= 9)
[3,5,6] : (3 + 6 <= 9)
[3,6] : (3 + 6 <= 9)

```
enter code here:

import java.lang.Math;
class Solution {
static int maxIndex=0;
static long M=1000000007;
public int numSubseq(int[] nums, int target) {
Arrays.sort(nums);
maxIndex=nums.length-1;
return numSubseq(nums,target,0);
}

public int numSubseq(int[] nums,int target, int i){
 if(target==0 || nums.length==0 || i==nums.length)
return 0;
int res=0;
if(2*nums[i]<=target){
     res=1;
    if(nums[i]<nums[maxIndex]){
        int j=maxIndex;
        while(j>i){
         if(nums[i]+nums[maxIndex]<=target)
             break;
            j--;
        }
        maxIndex=j;
        if(nums[i]+nums[maxIndex]<=target && i!=maxIndex) 
        {
            int diffIndex=maxIndex-i;
            res+=Math.pow(2,diffIndex)-1;
        }
        
       }
   }
      else{
           return 0;
     }
      return (int)((res+numSubseq(nums,target,i++))%M);
   }
}``
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain in more detail what problem the code is trying to solve, and show some example input and output? Also can you explain the general approach to solving the problem that you are trying to implement in the code? For example, why does the code use recursion? Also please format your code neatly so that it is easy to see how the brackets line up.

Comment: I am finding non-subsequences that contain the first number in array nums and rest number of non-zero subsequences are obtained using recursion.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate the problem. I propose to use hard-coded input.

Answer (score 1):

- I guess there would be a problem here in this line:

```
return (int)((res+numSubseq(nums,target,i++))%M);
```

- We can solve the problem a bit easier though, similarly using sort, then two pointers.

#### Test with a `b.java`:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    private static final int MOD = (int)1e9 + 7;
    public static final int numSubseq(
        final int[] nums,
        final int target
    ) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        int[] pows = new int[nums.length];
        pows[0] = 1;

        int subsequences = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int right = nums.length - 1;

        for (int index = 1 ; index < nums.length ; ++index) {
            pows[index] = pows[index - 1] * 2;
            pows[index] %= MOD;
        }

        while (left <= right) {
            if (nums[left] + nums[right] > target) {
                --right;

            } else {
                subsequences += pows[right - left++];
                subsequences %=  MOD;
            }
        }

        return subsequences;
    }
}


class b {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Solution().numSubseq(new int[] {3, 5, 6, 7}, 9));
        System.out.println(new Solution().numSubseq(new int[] {3, 3, 6, 8}, 10));
        System.out.println(new Solution().numSubseq(new int[] {2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7}, 12));
        System.out.println(new Solution().numSubseq(new int[] {5, 2, 4, 1, 7, 6, 8}, 16));
    }
}
```

#### prints

```
4
6
61
127
```